# How to run async operation in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, curl, task

I've got such requirements to build what I need:

- CLI task, that handles request messages from message queue (NATS is using);
- Every incoming message is a cURL package/object that should be placed for execution;
- Every new package should run asynchronously, so main task just placing all incoming requests in parallel threads (? or processes).

Problem is every async solution that I can find it like set of workers that always live in memory, but I want to dynamically place that jobs for work.

I also know about multi_curl - but this solution is really good when you need to execute a lot of ready cURL connections, but in my case this cURL connections appearing in a life time of project and should be executed as fast as it possible.

Comment: **Don't use PHP for this task**. Simple as that. PHP does not have built-in support for threading or asynchronous operations (unless you customize your PHP build, such as using `pthreads`, in which case you'll have a non-standard PHP environment).

Comment: The Problem is - that cURL package prepared in PHP and I don't know how to convert all that options to call it even using simple curl from bash.